# Eye the bull's-eye!

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story

Not too long ago, while I was hanging around in a sports club playing darts, I met a friend. We talked for a while. When he suddenly came up with an idea of a puzzle. He grabbed a piece of paper and noted down something which looked like a cipher. He stood up and asked me to meet once I decipher the note. I asked him *"But you didn't tell the place to meet?"*. He just smiled and said *"Eye the bull's eye"* and took off.

The note looked like this -

> Fl itl kotbr epu verlyos.

**Can you help crack it?**

Comment: Aargh! I was trying out stuff with the thing you've just clarified. rot13(Gur gvgyr naq gur zrffntr yratgu znqr vg boivbhf rabhtu, va zl bcvavba.)

Comment: @M Oehm I thought it didn't got much attention and hence thought I made it ambiguous. :)

Comment: Well, for all my trying out I haven't gone anywhere so far, so maybe it wasn't that big a giveaway.

Comment: @M Oehm Okay cool. All the best :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your friend wants to meet at ...

> **McDonald's**

Here's why -

> Dartboards have scores ranging 1-20 around the outside; clockwise from top-center, the scores are **20 1 18 4 13 6 10 15 2 17 3 19 7 16 8 11 14 9 12 5**
>
>  Wrapping the message around the dartboard, starting from the "1" which seems a sensible starting point, the letters map thus:
>    **1=F, 18=L, 4=I, 13=T, 6=L, 10=K, 15=O, 2=T, 17=B, 3=R,**
>    **19=E, 7=P, 16=U, 8=V, 11=E, 14=R, 9=L, 12=Y, 5=O, 20=S**
>
>  Now sorting those numerically, you get this:
>    **1=F, 2=T, 3=R, 4=I, 5=O, 6=L, 7=P, 8=V, 9=L, 10=K,**
>    **11=E, 12=Y, 13=T, 14=R, 15=O, 16=U, 17=B, 18=L, 19=E, 20=S**
>  or:
>      **FTRIOLPVLKEYTROUBLES**
>
>  Decrypting "FTRIOLPVL" with Vigenére key "TROUBLES" gives:
>    **MCDONALDS**
>
>  Go get your burger on.  Have a Shamrock Shake for me!

Comment: A free Shamrock Shake is on the way! :)